# How many 3 digit numbers are there such that the sum of its digits $\ge$ 10?

Tags: permutations

For example,the sum of the digits of the number $139=1+3+9=13$
The smallest $3$ digit number to fulfill this condition is $109$

Essentially,this question is asking "For three whole numbers $x,y,z$ find the number of permutations such that $x+ 
 y+ z$ $\ge$ 10, $ x \neq 0$(since hundreds digit can't be $0$)"

I want to know how we would calculate the final answer.

I also want to know the formula for this question if it was extended to n digit numbers.

Comment: Do you consider $091$ a three digit number?

Comment: Yes, since $ 901$ is.

Comment: No, since 091 will simplify to a 2 digit number.The hundreds digit cannot be 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, There are $900$ three digit numbers.  So if we find out how many $3$ digit number have the digits add up to $9$ or less we just subtract those.

Now consider this:

Suppose the three digit number is $abc$.

Suppose you are given $9$ stars and $3$ bars and you want to represent you number this way.

From left to right: Put down $a$ stars to represent the first digit. But down $1$ bar to represent a place holder.  Put down $b$ more stars to represent the second digit.  Put down a second bar to represent a $2$nd place holder. Put down $c$ stars.  Put a bar as the $3$rd place holder. You have $a+b+c \le 9$ so you may have some stars remaining.  Put them down.

Every three digit number where the sum is $9$ or less can be represented by a unique combination of stars and bars and each combination represents a unique three digit number where the sums of the digits is $9$ or less.

THis is a line of $12$ items and you must choose $3$ positions for where the bars go.

So there are ${12\choose 3}$ such numbers.

But notice we can't have the first digit be $0$.  That is, we can't start with a bar.

So given we start with a star we have $11$ more items and we must choose $3$ position for where the bars go.

So there are ${11 \choose 3}$ such number that have three digits, the first digit is not zero, and the digits add to $9$ or less.

SO there are $900-{11\choose 3}$ three digit numbers where the digits add up to $10$ or more.

Answer (score 1):

We could try to evaluate directly how Manu such number exist by conditionning on a particular digit. I'll do it with the last numbers.

If the last digit is $9$. Since the first digit is at least one, any three digits numbers is valid.
$$9\times10=90$$
If the last digit is $8$. If the first digit is $1$, there is $9$ possibilities for the second digit. Any other value of the first digit have $10$ possibilities for second digit. So
$$9+8\times10=89$$
If the last digit is $7$. If the first digit is $1$, there is $8$ possibilities for the second digit. If the first digit is $2$, there is $9$ possibilities for the second digit. Any other value of the first digit have $10$ possibilities for second digit. So
$$8+9+7\times10=87$$
So on for the other cases
$$7+8+9+6\times10=84$$
$$6+7+8+9+5\times10=80$$
$$5+6+7+8+9+4\times10=75$$
$$4+5+6+7+8+9+3\times10=69$$
$$3+4+5+6+7+8+9+2\times10=62$$
$$2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+1\times10=54$$
$$1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+0\times10=45$$
All is left is to add those possibilities.
$$90+89+87+84+80+75+69+62+54+45=735$$
It is longer than @fleablood answer, but it confirm the result since
$$900-{11\choose3}=900-165=735$$